# Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id .. amistad views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I am using amistad as a friends controller. now I want to add friend but the error I get is :

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id..
```

this is my link to add friend :

```
<section>
      <h1>
        <%= @user.username %>
      </h1>

    <% unless current_user == @user  %>
<%= link_to "Arkadaşlarıma Ekle", friends_path(:friend_id => @user), :method => :post,class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <%end %>
      </section>
```

and my friendships_controller.rb:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @friends = current_user.friends
    @pending_invited_by = current_user.pending_invited_by
    @pending_invited = current_user.pending_invited
  end

  def new
    @users = User.all :conditions => ["id != ?", current_user.id]
  end

  def create
    invitee = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
    if current_user.invite invitee
      redirect_to new_friend_path, :notice => "Successfully invited friend!"
    else
      redirect_to new_friend_path, :notice => "Sorry! You can't invite that user!"
    end
  end

  def update
    inviter = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if current_user.approve inviter
      redirect_to new_friend_path, :notice => "Successfully confirmed friend!"
    else
      redirect_to new_friend_path, :notice => "Sorry! Could not confirm friend!"
    end
  end

  def requests
    @pending_requests = current_user.pending_invited_by
  end

  def invites
    @pending_invites = current_user.pending_invited
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if current_user.remove_friendship user
      redirect_to friends_path, :notice => "Successfully removed friend!"
    else
      redirect_to friends_path, :notice => "Sorry, couldn't remove friend!"
    end
  end 

end
```

how can i arrange the correct views for amistad ? is there a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is a little bit messy but I suppose that the mistake is that you're sending a param "friend_id" but in your create action, you're trying to load a user with a param called "user_id". Probably the method:

```
current_user.invite invitee
```

is being called with invitee being nil so you're getting this error.

Hope it helps! :)